# Liferay 7 & JUnit : Mock Local Custom Local Service Util

Tags: junit, mockito, liferay, junit4, liferay-7

I'm trying to mock with powermockito my custom local service util, but i always get an error.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ServiceSubscriptionLocalServiceUtil.class})
public class CStreamTest {
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        .........
        mockStatic(ServiceSubscriptionLocalServiceUtil.class);
        .........
    }
}
```

and i'm getting the following error :

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor4.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.newInstance(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:48)
>       at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.newInstance(ObjenesisBase.java:73)
>       at org.mockito.internal.creation.instance.ObjenesisInstantiator.newInstance(ObjenesisInstantiator.java:19)
>       at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.java:47)
>       at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(ByteBuddyMockMaker.java:25)
>       at org.powermock.api.mockito.mockmaker.PowerMockMaker.createMock(PowerMockMaker.java:41)
>       at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:35)
>       at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:62)
>       at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1896)
>       at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.createMethodInvocationControl(DefaultMockCreator.java:108)
>       at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.doCreateMock(DefaultMockCreator.java:61)
>       at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.createMock(DefaultMockCreator.java:53)
>       at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.mock(DefaultMockCreator.java:40)
>       at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic(PowerMockito.java:62)
>       at com.e.c.stream.impl.test.CStreamTest.setUp(CStreamTest.java:50)

i add some parts of my pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.24.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: what are you powermock and mockito versions?

Comment: update my post with my pom.xml

Comment: @PrepareForTest({ServiceSubscriptionLocalServiceUtil.class.class}). tried with one .class?

Comment: does ServiceSubscriptionLocalServiceUtil have a no-arg constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Liferay's `*LocalServiceUtil` classes contain a bunch of static methods that just simplify the lookup of an actual service implementation. Given that you state you're on Liferay 7, you should just utilize the services themselves and rely on `@Reference` dependency management and injection in the code that uses them. This way you just need to mock a regular interface that is not loaded with some default implementation and lookup.

Another option is to test the implementation - and write tests for the code "above" the service, as well as its implementation. It's typically hard to write UI-layer code, e.g. portlets, in a test-driven fashion, where mocking isn't heavily dependent on the implementation of the service and the calling classes.

Comment: ok i understand. So how i should do that with @ Reference ? add this : @ Reference
    private ServiceSubscriptionLocalService serviceSubscriptionLocalService; ?? and use serviceSubscriptionLocalService in when methods of mockito ?

Comment: If I use the @ Reference like just above, I have serviceSubscriptionLocalService null and i make : when(serviceSubscriptionLocalService.findSubscribedServiceExist(code, 1)).thenReturn(subscriptionEmpty);

Comment: When you mock the service, you're creating a mock on the interface (`*LocalSercice`) and pass that around. As your test doesn't run in the OSGi runtime (I guess), you will need to call the setter yourself, in order to inject your mock service to the class under test.

Comment: I don't know what to do : 

@ Reference  
private ServiceSubscriptionLocalService serviceSubscriptionLocalService;

@ Before
    public void setUp() throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        .........
        mockStatic(ServiceSubscriptionLocalService.class);
        .........
    }

@ Test
    public void testGetServicesIfServiceIsNull()  {
when(serviceSubscriptionLocalService.findSubscribedServiceExist(code, 1)).thenReturn(subscriptionEmpty);
}

Answer (score 0):

Normally services utility classes created by Service builder do not have a no arg constructor, not even a constructor for that matter.
But if you check the log you will see and this is your issue:

New instance of the class is created inside PowerMock.

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor4.newInstance(Unknown Source)
After trying to create an instance for: ObjenesisBase....

Even though it has not constructors, services **utils normally initialize static members**, like a ServiceTracker.

You could create a bummy service impl or your code could use the service reference instead of the util, you could mock that guy. Several options here, even mocking methods that give you the service to give you a dummy service.

But in summary, you cannot just do:

```
mockStatic(ServiceSubscriptionLocalServiceUtil.class);
```

As this will create an instance, and that instance has static members that need to be initialized.

Comment: this class is really not test friendly if you are not running your test in an OSGi runtime. My suggestion is, code a dummy class, it can have the static methods you need and use the same interface. Implement a getter yourself in the subject class, and in your tests you return that dummy.